# swift programming language

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to learn a new coding language called swift. But I got a question in mind.

```
import UIkit

func makeACake (cash:Double, ratio:Double){
print(Making \(cash*ratio)pounds of cake")
}

makeACake(cash:10,ratio:3)
```

// it will print making 30.0 pounds of cake.

just two questions here.

no.1
why cant i just   call  makeACake(10,3)  why do i have to type it  in this manner makeACake(cash:10,ratio:3)

no.2
is the function println removed from swift? why cant i use the function println and it asked me to use print instead.

sorry if i happened to ask any stupid question. but yea just trying to learn coding so maybe help a newbie out? thank you and bless the person who would be kind enough to help me and let me move on.

Comment: Just update you statement to `func makeACake (_ cash:Double, _ ratio:Double){
print(Making \(cash*ratio)pounds of cake")
}`

Comment: You can learn at: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Comment: tried your method but now it state missing argument labels ' _cash:_ratio:' in call makeACake(10,3)

Comment: As @Paul says, use _ to avoid the need to name parameters on the call. Regarding this and your println question: each language has its own way of doing things. Sometimes they borrow from current or previous languages, but more often they go their own way. You need to get used to this. The Swift documentarion explains all this quite well.

Comment: hahaah nvm i got what yall meant. Thanks!

Comment: just another question, theres no more println in swift anymore right?

Comment: @Reuben correct, println is other languages, Swift uses print for that functionality.

Comment: No problem. FYI for future questions: please only one question per post and make the title summarise what  you are asking. The idea is to make questions and answers useful to others.

Comment: Please consider that it is an intended concept of Swift to include the parameter labels for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

Every programing language has their own syntax.

Basically, this syntax is acquired from their parent language. The syntax is getting changed in every update.
I have started with swift2 and lot has been changed from swift2 to swift4.

So answering your question,

**Answer 1:** **(_) Underscore** --> It is ***Wildcard pattern***

> A wildcard pattern matches and ignores any value and consists of an
>   underscore (_). Use a wildcard pattern when you don’t care about the
>   values being matched against.

In your example, It means that argument labels are not necessary on invocation of your function.

Learn more about patter at: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html

So if you dont want to write parameter name write:

```
func makeACake ( _ cash:Double, _ ratio:Double){}
```

**Answer 2:** **print**: *Introduce First in swift2*, we used to type println in swift.
Now you might ask why println was removed, and the answer is simple ***"It is no longer required"***.

Let me take a simple example:

```
println("Hello")
println("World")
```

output: (One next line is extra in output, don't know how to format it here)

> Hello
>
> World

While with print

```
print("Hello")
print("World")
```

> output: HelloWorld

Later in swift2 println was deprecated and the same("Next Line") output can be achieved with print itself.

"Evolution"
They are making swift "Easy to Learn", "Easy to code" language